# Save databound table information spread across 3 tabs vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, bindingsource

I have a Windows form with a tab control on it.  I have fields from one bindingsource on 3 tabs of the tab control.   I can open the form and change data on all 3 tabs and navigate between tabs and my changes are there.   When I click on the 'Save' button on the BindingNaviator, not all of my changes are saved to the table I am bound to.   Is there something special that needs to be done to not lose the changes?

Comment: Are all the controls data bound by dragging fields from the table onto the tabs? Are there any of the controls not bound this way? This assumes you have used the IDE data wizard to create the data source that creates TableAdapters etc.

Comment: Yes, they are all dragged on from the 'Data Sources' section on the left.

Comment: In this case I can't see any reason why all fields in the one table would not save using the built in save code added to the form when dragging table data onto the tabs.

Comment: When I originally created the form, I dragged all of the fields onto the form, then added the tab control and moved the fields on to each tab.   I am going to try to recreate it by creating the form, then tab control, and then dragging the fields to the appropriate tab page and see if that changes the behavior

Comment: Should not make a difference but try anyways. If you were to look at the form,Designer,vb file, look at the controls, you will see that there are five properties set, one being DataBindings.Add... make sure they are all correct,

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  On Tab2 of my tab control I have some number fields.   There is also a checkbox the user can select to set those number fields to 100, and if they uncheck it, it was setting the the .text property of those to "".   The fields should be set to 0 instead of a blank.   After I made this change, it works fine.   Thanks for the help.